# Swift 3 Programmatically Created Button Not Clickable

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have created a subview programmatically, then added a button to said subview programmatically. I used anchor constraints to set the position of the button within the subview and the button now appears on the subview exactly where I want it to. However, the button is not clickable. I have found that the frame of the button is (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), which is likely the cause of my issues. My question is, how does the button appear normal (yet is unclickable) while the frame is 0. The code I used to instantiate and constrain the button is below. Thank you for the help.

```
var confirmButton: UIButton = {
    var button = UIButton()
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 41/255, green: 154/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)
    button.setTitle("Continue", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    button.isEnabled = true
    return button
}()



promptView.addSubview(confirmButton)

        confirmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.continuePressed), for: .touchUpInside)

        confirmButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: promptView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        confirmButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: promptView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        confirmButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: promptView.bottomAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        //confirmButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: promptView.topAnchor, constant: -235)
        confirmButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

Comment: Make sure that you set the `promptview`'s `isUserInteractionEnabled` property to true

Comment: @Paulw11 has a good suggestion. Where are you finding a CGRect.zero frame for the button? It's very possible that it's frame isn't yet set - try finding the frame value in the controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` function. (It makes no sense whatsoever that a viewable UIView has no frame.) I ran into issues like this one time before - it took some time, but I realized that a UISlider created, visible, and added as a subview in code like the UIButton *also* didn't work. If I remember, it had to do with the view hierarchy somehow.

Comment: No luck with setting promptView's isUserInteractionEnabled. Im printing the frame of confirmButton directly beneath the constraints

Comment: I think I was thrown off by the strange frame print out. The button is now working, but does not look like its being clicked. How can I activate this feature?

Answer (score -2):

your code is almost right..i have run your code in my project and everything working properly..you can see my code its same as you did..

```
    var confirmButton: UIButton = {
    var button = UIButton()
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 41/255, green: 154/255, blue: 245/255, 
    alpha: 1)
    button.setTitle("Continue", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    button.isEnabled = true
    return button
    }()

    var promptView : UIView = {
        let viewPrompt = UIView()
        viewPrompt.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        viewPrompt.layer.masksToBounds = true
        viewPrompt.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 41/255, green: 154/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)
        return viewPrompt
    }()


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            view.addSubview(promptView)
            promptView.addSubview(confirmButton)

    promptView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: promptView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        view.addConstraint(centerX)

        let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: promptView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        view.addConstraint(centerY)

        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: promptView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)
        promptView.addConstraint(height)

        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: promptView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)
        promptView.addConstraint(width)

            confirmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.continuePressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            confirmButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: promptView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        confirmButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: promptView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        confirmButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: promptView.bottomAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        confirmButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true  
    }

    func continuePressed(_ sender : UIButton ){
        print("Hello")
    }
```

hope it work for you!!!

Comment: If the code is "almost right" please explain where it is wrong.